# Is there any evidence for "altercate" ever having been pronounced with stress on the second syllable?

Tags: verbs, pronunciation, historical-change, early-modern-english, stress

In modern English, polysyllabic verbs ending in *-ate* are regularly stressed on the third-to-last syllable. (There are some (possible) exceptions, such as *incarnate, impregnate,* and *elongate.*)

But it seems that certain speakers in the past followed a different rule, whereby the stress fell on the second-to-last syllable when it was "closed" (ended in a consonant) in Latin. A well-known example of an *-ate* verb that used to have this stress pattern is *contemplate;* the Oxford English Dictionary entry for this word summarizes the situation as follows:

> In a few rare cases (Shakespeare, *Hudibras*) stressed *ˈcontemplate* in 16–17th cent.; also by Kenrick 1773, Webster 1828, among writers on pronunciation. Byron, Shelley, and Tennyson have both modes, but the orthoepists generally have *conˈtemplate* down to third quarter of 19th cent.; since that time *ˈcontemplate* has more and more prevailed, and *conˈtemplate* begins to have a flavour of age. This is the common tendency with all verbs in *-ate.* Of these, the antepenult stress is historical in all words in which the penult represents a short Latin syllable, as *acˈcelerate, ˈanimate, ˈfascinate, ˈmachinate, ˈmilitate,* or one prosodically short or long, as in *ˈcelebrate, ˈconsecrate, ˈemigrate;* regularly also when the penult has a vowel long in Latin, as *ˈalienate, ˈaspirate, conˈcatenate, ˈdenudate, eˈlaborate, ˈindurate, ˈpersonate, ˈruinate* (Latin *aliēno, aspīro,* etc.). But **where the penult has two or three consonants giving positional length, the stress has historically been on the penult,** and its shift to the antepenult is recent or still in progress, as in ***acervate***, adumbrate, **alternate**, compensate, concentrate, condensate, confiscate, conquassate, constellate, demonstrate, decussate, desiccate, **enervate**, **exacerbate**, exculpate, illustrate, inculcate, **objurgate**, etc., all familiar with penult stress to middle-aged men. The influence of the noun of action in *-ation* is a factor in the change; thus the analogy of *ˌconseˈcration, ˈconsecrate,* etc., suggests *ˌdemonˈstration, ˈdemonstrate.* But there being no *remonstration* in use, *reˈmonstrate,* supported by *reˈmonstrance,* keeps the earlier stress.

(bolding added for emphasis)

Based on this information, I thought that the rare verb *altercate* must have used to have a pronunciation with stress on the second-to-last syllable. But I've had some trouble finding material that supports my guess.

The Oxford English Dictionary gives the present-day pronunciations as "Brit. /ˈɔːltəkeɪt/, /ˈɒltəkeɪt/, U.S. /ˈɔltərˌkeɪt/, /ˈɑltərˌkeɪt/" and has a note saying "N.E.D. (1884) also gives the pronunciation as (æ·ltəɹkeit) /ˈæltəkeɪt/" (which is interesting, but doesn't answer my question).

One of the earlier OED citations, from F. Quarles *Divine Fancies* i. xl (the OED gives the date as 1632), uses the word in verse in a context where it seems it would have to scan as stressed-unstressed-stressed:

> Whenas my Body and my Soule shall plight
>   
>  Inviolable faith, and never fight 
>   
>  Nor wrangle more, nor **altercate**, again,
>   
>  About that strife-begetting question, *Sin !*

(*[The Complete Works in Prose and Verse of Francis Quarles](https://books.google.com/books?id=2_gUAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA206&lpg=PA206&dq=Never%20fight%20Nor%20wrangle%20more,%20nor%20altercate%20agin.&source=bl&ots=a9j2Myfz1M&sig=zjQSdb577ExMrvcH_bdk-bm-3VY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC2tfxxLvaAhVj94MKHTeUCAsQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=Never%20fight%20Nor%20wrangle%20more%2C%20nor%20altercate%20agin.&f=false),* by Alexander B. Grosart, 1880)

Annoyingly, the verb doesn't seem to have an entry in John Walker's *[Critical Pronunciation Dictionary](https://archive.org/stream/acriticalpronou00conggoog#page/n108/mode/2up)* of 1791, although Walker evidently was familar with it since he uses it in the definitions of "to chop" and "to stickle" (though the "stickle" definition doesn't seem to have originated with Walker, as it can also be found in [Sheridan's dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=rBFJAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP361&dq=%22altercate%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEvd7dzLvaAhUr7oMKHVEvCaUQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22altercate%22&f=false) and [Johnson's dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=m2ITAAAAQAAJ&pg=PT237&dq=%22altercate%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEvd7dzLvaAhUr7oMKHVEvCaUQ6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=%22altercate%22&f=false)).

The 21st edition of Nathan Bailey's *[Universal Etymological English Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Universal_Etymological_English_Dictionary)* (1775) gives the [stress on the first syllable](https://books.google.com/books?id=CFBGAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP50&dq=%22altercate%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEvd7dzLvaAhUr7oMKHVEvCaUQ6AEIQTAE#v=onepage&q=%22altercate%22&f=false).

Does anyone know of any evidence for stress ever falling on the second syllable of *altercate* in the past? I'm thinking the most likely place such information would appear is in old dictionaries or poems. The OED's earliest citation for the verb is from 1530.

Answer (score 1):

Samuel Johnson’s dictionary of 1755 has no entry for *altercate*, but tantalizingly does have one for the verb *[alternate](http://johnsonsdictionaryonline.com/page-view/?i=117)*, where he indicates the stress on the second syllable (like *alternative*), adducing a citation from Milton where the meter suggests that pronunciation. The entries for the adjective and noun are also instructive.

[image]

Thomas Dyche’s spelling dictionary of 1737, however, shows Johnson’s pronunciation of *alternate*, but an accent on the first syllable for [*altercate*](https://archive.org/stream/bub_gb_1He4RA4E6gwC#page/n15/mode/2up/search/altercate):

[image]

Comment: Yeah, part of the reason I supposed a pronunciation of "altercate" with stress on the second syllable existed at some point is because it seemed unlikely to me that people used "alTERnate" alongside "ALtercate". But I don't know, maybe they did?

Comment: Well, you could do as Johnson did, see if Milton used it. I don't know if PL and/or PR are searchable online, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I agree, but it's been difficult for me to do research because I'm not sure how to do a search online for words in old poetry (in general--there are sites that let you look up a word in e.g. Shakespeare's poetry).

Comment: @sumelic: See edit to my answer.

Comment: @sumelic: the word also appears in several quite early bilingual dictionaries, like this French one from 1530, but unfortunately with no pronunciation guide. The examples given are all prose. https://archive.org/stream/rosettaproject_fra_detail-1#page/n516/mode/1up/search/altercate