# What determines the stress of an adjective formed by adding "-ive" to a verb ending in "-ate"?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, pronunciation, suffixes

Some verbs ending in *-ate* keep their original syllable stress when you add the suffix *-ive* to form an adjective

e.g.,

> imit*ate*/imitat*ive*
>
> medit*ate*/meditat*ive*
>
> investig*ate*/investigat*ive*

For others, the stress moves to the antepenultimate syllable and the 'a' in *-ative* is reduced;

e.g.,

> indic*ate*/indic*ative*
>
> contempl*ate*/contempl*ative*
>
> interrog*ate*/interrog*ative*

Is there a rule or any kind of historical reason why a word would follow one pattern or the other?

Comment: +1 However, please try to add your own contribution to the effort at finding an answer.

Comment: Some words can be pronounced both ways, such as illustrative and contemplative. There are many more of these words that I hear people speak with variable placement of syllable stress, though for the few I've checked dictionaries don't attest to multiple pronunciations. Still, you'll find a lot of variation in spoken English.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no real "rule" (definitely no useful rule, at least).

Frequency and age of the word probably has an effect (with *-ative* words that are older and more frequent being more likely to have a pronunciation with no stress on the penult). I wrote an answer to an earlier question about the position of stress in *-ative* words ([Is there a rule for the position of the accent (stressed sound) in words ending with -ative?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307413)) which mentions that three-syllable words ending in *-ative* are mostly stressed on the first syllable (only one exception that I know of, *creative*).

For *contemplative,* it's possibly relevant that the verb *contemplate* used to have a pronunciation with stress on the penult syllable (this was once a common pronunciation pattern for many *-ate* verbs that contained heterosyllabic consonant clusters in Latin; see the OED quote in my question here: [Is there any evidence for "altercate" ever having been pronounced with stress on the second syllable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/441747/is-there-any-evidence-for-altercate-ever-having-been-pronounced-with-stress-on)). *Alternative* and sometimes *illustrative* have the same stress pattern.